# How to redirect www add on domain to non www? - I think it's a bit more complex than the title may make it seem

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

As the title states, I'm trying to 301 redirect the wwww version of a site to non-www. Simple right? Well I've tried a bunch of things already and I have ultimately come up short. I think my situation is a bit more complex than how it may seem at first glance so I'll try to provide as much detail as possible below.

There are 3 domains hosted on the same server:
Main domain: `example.com`
Add on domain: `example.com.au`
Add on domain: `example.com.mx`

The main domain, `https://example.com` does have the 301 from `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` set up correctly. So no problems there. However, the add on domains `example.com.au` and `example.com.mx` do not have the 301 redirects set up. Also, for both of these add on domains, the www versions show the following message when you visit their pages:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   www.example.com.au (for example, passwords, messages, or credit
>   cards).

Sorry for being a total noob but not sure if these details are important. But I figure I should provide them anyway just in case.

All the domains are on the same platform - Magento
All the domains share the same document root folder of course sharing the same .htaccess file

I tried a few different things with the htaccess file but unfortunately nothing worked... I also tried doing the redirects in cPanel but nothing happened. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you access all domains using https, so there might be a problem with SSL certificates. Make sure you have wildcard (*.example.com.au and *.example.com.mx) certificates for both add on domains.

[Here is a instruction, how to do it in cPanel.](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache-cpanel.htm)

Comment: There is a standard UCC SSL certificate which the main domain 'example.com' and the 2 add on domains are using ('example.com.au' and 'example.com.mx'). The 'https://www.example.com' is redirecting to 'https://example.com' but this is not the case with add on domains. Are you saying I would need a wildcard cert in order for the add on domains 'https://www.example.com.au' and 'https://www.example.com.mx' to redirect to their respective non-www URLs? I thought that the wildcard certificate was needed only if you were using the subdomain. I thought it wasn't needed if you were just redirecting.

Comment: [It seems so.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate#Example) Can you check what domains are included in UCC SSL? Is there www.example.com? Maybe you could add those two add on domains to the certificate with www subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

in .htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine on
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```